# After reinstalling Django due to computer crash, I am getting following error when I try to access the models in my app

Tags: python, django

After reinstalling Django due to computer crash, I am getting following error when I try to access the models in my app. What could be possible solution? Previously I did not set any environment variable but still working fine.

```
  File "C:\Users\VaibhavK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packag
es\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, b
ut settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Hi Vaibhav Kale. Does this help? : https://medium.com/@alokkumar_17171/django-error-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-ed0b9023cfc9

Answer (score 0):

variable need to define

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Comment: Now I am getting the following error. Here "mod" is the name of my project.

>>> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mod.settings.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mod.settings.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: are you on linux or windows? on linux use "export" different on windows use "set" instead .